# Finding variance of X, the random variable that represents the number of isolated nodes in a random graph

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables, expected-value, variance

Assuming a random n-node graph that is undirected, can't have multi-edges or loops, consider a scenario in which each edge exists independently with probability p. Set a random variable X to be the number of isolated nodes.

I found $E[X] = n(1−p)^{n-1}$

I know that $Var[X] = E[X^2] + E[X]^2$

Would I be correct in saying $Var[X] = (n(1−p)^{n-1})^2 + n$ because of the proposition that for the random variable $Sn$ defined as $S_{n} = X_1 + X_2 +... + X_n$, $E[S_n^2] = n$? Because I'm setting $X_i$ to be an indicator variable, where it's one if the i'th node is isolated and 0 otherwise, and $X = X_1 + X_2 +...+X_n$ is essentially the $S_n$

Or is this invalid?

Comment: Nice attempt, but not quite correct.  The square of a sum is not the sum of squares.   Also, $\mathsf {Var}(X)=\mathsf E(X^2)~\mathbf -~\mathsf E(X)^2$

Comment: @GrahamKemp thanks for the reply! In what case could you use that proposition?

Answer (score 1):

When $(X_i)$ is the sequence of indicator functions for isolation, then $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ will count the isolated nodes.

Now the expectation, $\mathsf E(X_i)$, is the probability that node $i$ is isolated from each of the $n-1$ remaining nodes, which is: $(1-p)^{n-1}$.

Since each $X_i$ has Bernoulli distribution, the expectation of ${X_i}^2$ equals the expectation of $X_i$.$$\begin{align}\mathsf{Var}(X_i)&=\mathsf E({X_i}^2)-\mathsf E(X_i)^2\\[1ex]&=(1-p)^{n-1}\,(1-(1-p)^{n-1})\end{align}$$

---

So indeed.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(S_n) &=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathsf E(X_i)&&\text{linearity of expectation}\\[1ex]&= n\,\mathsf E(X_1)&&\text{identical distributions}\\[1ex]&=n\,(1-p)^{n-1}&&\text{.}\end{align}$$

---

**However** for the expectation of the square of the sum, things are not linear. The square of a sum is *not* the sum of squares :  $~(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$ .

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E\left({S_n}^2\right)&=\mathsf E\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\cdot\sum_{j=1}^n X_j\right)\\&=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathsf E\left({X_i}^2\right)+2\sum_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}\,\mathsf E(X_iX_j)\\[1ex] &= n\mathsf E({X_1}^2)+ n(n-1)\,\mathsf E(X_1X_2)\\[1ex]&= n~(1-p)^{n-1}+ n(n-1)\,\mathsf E(X_1X_2)\end{align}$$

That leaves you to evaluate the probability that two particular nodes are both isolated, $\mathsf E(X_1X_2)$.

Comment: It is the probability that these two nodes are disconnected from each other, and *both* are disconnected from the $n-2$ remaining nodes

Comment: gotcha! But if the expectation of $X_{i}^2$ equals the expectation of $X_i$ isnt the variance just 0?

Comment: also, where did the 2 go?

Comment: $\mathsf E({X_i}^2)$ equals $\mathsf E(X_i)$, which does not equal $\mathsf E(X_i)\,^2$.

Comment: also, are you refering to $2\sum_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}\mathsf E(X_iX_j)=n(n-1)\mathsf E(X_1X_2)$ ? There are $\tfrac 12n(n-1)$ points in $\{\langle i,j\rangle\in\Bbb N^2: 1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n\}$  Recall Triangle Numbers.  Also it is $^n\mathrm C_2$ ... the count for ways to select $2$ elements from a set of $n$.